# XSL sorting of two node sets

Tags: sorting, xslt

I have an input XML like this:-

```
<Results>
<School>
    <Name>A</Name>
    <Location>
        <StreetAddress>abc</StreetAddress>
        <Distance>5</Distance>
    </Location>
    <Location>
        <StreetAddress>def</StreetAddress>
        <Distance>3</Distance>
    </Location>
    <Location>
        <StreetAddress>xyz</StreetAddress>
        <Distance>6</Distance>
    </Location>
</School>
<School>
    <Name>B</Name>
    <Location>
        <StreetAddress>abc1</StreetAddress>
        <Distance>7</Distance>
    </Location>
    <Location>
        <StreetAddress>def2</StreetAddress>
        <Distance>6</Distance>
    </Location>
    <Location>
        <StreetAddress>xyz3</StreetAddress>
        <Distance>2</Distance>
    </Location>
</School>
<School>
    <Name>C</Name>
    <Location>
        <StreetAddress>abc4</StreetAddress>
        <Distance>2</Distance>
    </Location>
    <Location>
        <StreetAddress>def5</StreetAddress>
        <Distance>1</Distance>
    </Location>
    <Location>
        <StreetAddress>xyz6</StreetAddress>
        <Distance>0.5</Distance>
    </Location>
</School>
```

Using XSL v1, I need to sort the Location nodes on Distance and then sort the schools on minimum distance
Basically the output should look something like this

```
<Results>
<School>
    <Name>C</Name>
    <Location>
        <StreetAddress>xyz6</StreetAddress>
        <Distance>0.5</Distance>
    </Location>
    <Location>
        <StreetAddress>def5</StreetAddress>
        <Distance>1</Distance>
    </Location>
    <Location>
        <StreetAddress>abc4</StreetAddress>
        <Distance>2</Distance>
    </Location>
</School>   
<School>
    <Name>B</Name>
    <Location>
        <StreetAddress>xyz3</StreetAddress>
        <Distance>2</Distance>
    </Location>
    <Location>
        <StreetAddress>def2</StreetAddress>
        <Distance>6</Distance>
    </Location>
    <Location>
        <StreetAddress>abc1</StreetAddress>
        <Distance>7</Distance>
    </Location>
</School>
<School>
    <Name>A</Name>
    <Location>
        <StreetAddress>def</StreetAddress>
        <Distance>3</Distance>
    </Location>
    <Location>
        <StreetAddress>abc</StreetAddress>
        <Distance>5</Distance>
    </Location>
    <Location>
        <StreetAddress>xyz</StreetAddress>
        <Distance>6</Distance>
    </Location>
</School>
```

I am able to do this by first sorting the nodes based on Distance, storing them in a variable and then sorting it again on /Results/School/Location[1]/Distance.

I am wondering if there is a way to perform all this in one go.

Appreciate your help.

Answer (score 0):

With XSLT 2.0 you could easily do

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

<xsl:output indent="yes"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

<xsl:template match="@* | node()">
  <xsl:copy>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
  </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="Results">
  <xsl:copy>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="School">
      <xsl:sort select="min(Location/Distance/number(.))"/>
    </xsl:apply-templates>
  </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="School">
  <xsl:copy>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="Name"/>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="Location">
      <xsl:sort select="number(Distance)"/>
    </xsl:apply-templates>
  </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

With XSLT 1.0 I think your approach with sorting into a variable is the right one.